# I want donot have page number in the top and bottom of the pages

Tags: page-numbering

I want to remove the number pages from the file. How can I do? Please help me.

Comment: `pagestyle{empty}` would be the easiest thing, but however, this depends on the class or style file.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your current set-up. It will then be much easier for us to provide relevant solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can gobble the numbers this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage{lipsum} % not needed in real document

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-40] % dummy text
\end{document}
```

Of course, better option is to use a pagestyle that removes them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{lipsum} % not needed in real document

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-40] % dummy text
\end{document}
```